# TP-Link AC600 T2E Archer PCI-e card not working

Tags: wireless, pcie

My TP-Link AC600 T2E Archer PCI-e card is not working on Ubuntu 22.04 with kernal 5.11.15

The card is appearing in lspci but I'm unable to use WiFi. The card name is TP-Link AC600 T2E Archer dual band WiFi.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: How it happened that you are using an unsupported old 5.11.15 kernel on Ubuntu 22.04?